# ordered logistic regression with a four way interaction in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I have been trying to perform an ordered logistic regression with a four-way interaction and get the error message:

> Error in Design(eval.parent(m)) :    interaction term not second or
>   third order

The design is:
Dependent variable: 
Developmental stage - 5 levels numbered 1-5

Independent variables:
Age - 4 different age points for which data was collected; 
Ancestry - 2 categories numbered 1 & 2; 
Rearing environment - 2 categories numbered 1 & 2; 
Current environment - 2 categories numbered 1 & 2

As there is the potential for pseudo-replication the model is run clustered by "Colony".

As such, the code that I have been trying to use is:

```
library(rms)

Data$Ancestry <- factor(Data$Ancestry)
Data$Rearing <- factor(Data$Rearing)
Data$Queenless <- factor(Data$Queenless)

m <- lrm(Level ~ Age *  Ancestry * Rearing * Queenless, x=T, y=T, dat = Data)

robcov(m, cluster = Data$Colony)
```

I'm assuming that the error message means that lrm doesn't support a 4-way interaction.  Is there another way of doing this?  I'm having no luck searching for alternate solutions online and I know I had problems trying to cluster using the polr function.

Many thanks for your help.

Here is my data:

```html
    structure(list(Bee.Age = c(8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L), Colony = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), .Label = c("A1", 
"A2", "A3", "A4", "E1", "E2", "E3", "E4", "I1", "I2"), class = "factor"), 
    Ancestry = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2"), class = "factor"), Queenless = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), Rearing = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
    LevelOA = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
    4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
    2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
    2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 
    4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L), X = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
    )), .Names = c("Bee.Age", "Colony", "Ancestry", "Queenless", 
"Rearing", "LevelOA", "X"), row.names = c(NA, -320L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please provide the data necessary to reproduce your error. You should also always include all `library` statements in your code. Please review http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and the R tag description: *"R is a free, open-source programming language and software environment for statistical computing, bioinformatics, and graphics. Please supplement your question with a minimal reproducible example. Use `dput()` for data and specify all non-base packages with library calls. For statistical questions please use http://stats.stackexchange.com."*

Comment: You could stick with `polr` and get clustered SEs using clustered bootstrap.

Comment: Based on a comment you made below can you please clarify if your question is 1. how to resolve the error when running a logit regression with 4 way interaction or 2. "how do I resolve this error and proceed to use the results for clustering my data by colony to remove the potential for pseduo replication"? Because if you're really asking the latter then your question is both *Too Broad* and *Off-topic for StackOverflow*.

Comment: While I appreciate the effort, we don't use DropBox for sharing data. Again, please see the R tag description and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Please either `dput` the data necessary for a Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example or use a built in data set to replicate your error / problem. Creating data within your code is also acceptable. The reason we don't use Dropbox and the like is a combination of making sure the data will remain available and for security.

Comment: Based on a comment you made below can you please clarify if your question is 1. how to resolve the error when running a logit regression with 4 way interaction or 2. "how do I resolve this error and proceed to use the results for clustering my data by colony to remove the potential for pseduo replication"? Because if you're really asking the latter then your question is both *Too Broad* and *Off-topic for StackOverflow*.  If it's the former then I believe I've already answered your question below. Just so you know, 3 people with closevote privileges have voted to close this question.

Comment: Thanks. It's vital that I cluster the results by colony as I did in the original code above as otherwise the results aren't reliable. I'm sorry if this is too broad a question/wasn't clear originally. I'm trying to run a 4-way interaction, ordered logistic regression with robust standard error clustering.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer.

If you need to fit an ordinal model with clustered data, you can use the `ordinal` package:

Process data:

```
 library(ordinal)
 Data <- transform(Data,
     Ancestry=factor(Ancestry),
     Rearing=factor(Rearing),
     Queenless=factor(Queenless),
     LevelOA=ordered(LevelOA))
```

The only special point here is that the response variable needs to be an ordered factor (`ordered()`).

There are two versions of clustered *cumulative-link* models in `ordinal` (you can read about their options in the package's help files):

```
c1 <- clmm(LevelOA ~ Bee.Age*Ancestry*Rearing*Queenless + (1|Colony),
     dat = Data)

c2 <- clmm2(ordered(LevelOA) ~ Bee.Age*Ancestry*Rearing*Queenless,
      random = Colony, data= Data, Hess=TRUE)
```

Both of these give estimates, but not standard deviations - I think the model is too complex and something is going wrong with the SD computation, but it would take more work (maybe a lot more) to figure it out.  The estimated among-colony variance is also nearly/effectively zero with both models (std. dev approx. 2.7e-5), which implies that   As a preliminary, you can use `MASS::polr` to fit the model without clustering:

```
c0 <- polr(LevelOA ~ Bee.Age *  Ancestry * Rearing * Queenless,
     dat = Data)
```

because the estimated among-colony variance is zero, this gives the same coefficient estimates as the `ordinal` functions.

Comment: Thank you Ben. I'm looking forward to trying your solutions in the morning.